# Autenticação com Passport Session no Android

Tags: android, node.js, cookies, express.js, passport-js

Tenho um web app rodando com NodeJS, Express e a autenticação com Passport-JS, e tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Agora eu estou desenvolvendo um app Android e preciso autenticar meus usuários usando a mesma API.

Pelo que eu entendi lendo a documentação e perguntas no SO gringo, o passport cria um cookie no navegador do cliente com o ID do usuário logado, e esse cookie é passado em todas as requisições do cliente ao servidor. O Servidor por sua vez consegue decodificar esse cookie e seta o req.user com essa id provinda do cookie, pra saber quem está requisitando a API.

Minha dúvida é, como posso fazer isso manualmente no Android, visto esse processo não ocorre de forma automática como no browser? Caso não seja possível usar essa estratégia, o que preciso mudar?

Links pra tutoriais ou blogs que ajudem também são muito bem vindos!

Pra referência, aqui está a parte da API que interessa nesse caso:

```
app.use(session({
    secret : 'hidden of course :)',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/****** Passport functions ******/
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.idUser);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : id } }).then(function (user, err) {
        done(null, user);
    });
});

//Facebook
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    //Information stored on config/auth.js
    clientID: *******,
    clientSecret: ******,
    callbackURL: *******,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName', 'name', 'gender', 'picture.type(large)'] 

}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //Using next tick to take advantage of async properties
    process.nextTick(function () {
        db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (user, err) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            } 
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                // Check whether the email is undefined or valid
                var emailTemp = '';
                if(profile.emails && profile.emails[0] && profile.emails[0].value) {
                    emailTemp = profile.emails[0].value;
                } else {
                    emailTemp = '';
                }

                var picture = '';
                if(profile.photos && profile.photos[0] && profile.photos[0].value) {
                    picture = profile.photos[0].value;
                } else {
                    picture = '/img/profile.png';
                }

                var sexFb = '';
                if(profile.gender) {
                    sexFb = profile.gender;
                } else {
                    sexFb = '';
                }

                // Create the user
                db.user.create({
                    idUser : profile.id,
                    token : accessToken,
                    picture : picture,
                    nameUser : profile.displayName,
                    email : emailTemp,
                    sex : sexFb
                }).then(function () {
                    db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (user, err) {
                        if(user) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

/* FACEBOOK STRATEGY */
// Redirect the user to Facebook for authentication.  When complete,
// Facebook will redirect the user back to the application at
//     /auth/facebook/callback//
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email']}));
/* FACEBOOK STRATEGY */
// Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function (req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('../../app.html');
});
```

E aqui um exemplo de uso, pra mostrar o que preciso ter (o req.user):

```
app.put('/profile', function (req, res) {
    //Updates the profile information of the user
    db.user.update({
        nameUser : req.body.nameUser
    }, {
        where : {
            idUser : req.user.idUser
        }
    }).then(function (user) {
        res.json({ yes : "yes" });
    });
});
```

Comment: Será que esse link ajuda?: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: @seamusd eu ja fiz esse tutorial, nao ajuda pois meu problema nao eh com autenticacao na web, isso funciona, mas sim em um app android usando a mesma api. Mas obrigado pela sugestao.

Comment: Isso deve te ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447076/nodejs-express-passport-going-mobile#answer-30770389

Answer (score 1):

O melhor jeito de manter sessão, cache entre outras coisas do usuário é através de uma interface que salva os dados na preferencia do usuário.
Para fazer isso 
Primeiro adicione um user agent na sua webview para a aplicação web saber de onde está vindo o acesso.

```
private static final String ANDROID_USER_AGENT = "AppAndroid";
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
String userAgent = settings.getUserAgentString();
if (!userAgent.endsWith(ANDROID_USER_AGENT)) {
    userAgent += " " + ANDROID_USER_AGENT;
}
settings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Depois disso crie uma interface no seu aplicativo

```
public class PreferencesJavascriptInterface {

@JavascriptInterface
public void setData(String key, String data) {
    PreferenceUtils.set(key, data);
}

@JavascriptInterface
public String getData(String key) {
    return PreferenceUtils.get(key);
}

}
```

Esse PreferenceUtils é uma classe que salva e pega os dado que você envia para essa interface.

```
public class PreferenceUtils {

public static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "APP_PREFERENCES";

private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static void init(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static void set(String key, String value) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
}

public static String get(String key) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
}
}
```

No seu application você vai ter que iniciar essa classe preferenceutils, desse modo:

```
PreferenceUtils.init(this);
```

Na sua webview você vai ter que adicionar essa interface desse modo:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PreferencesJavascriptInterface(), "Android");
```

No seu front você vai verificar se o usuário está acessando de um dispositivo android a partir do user agent.

Vai ter que adicionar esse javascript

```
 NativeBridge
var NativeBridge = {
  callbacksCount: 1,
  callbacks: {},
  // Automatically called by native layer when a result is available
  resultForCallback: function (callbackId, resultArray) {
    try {
      var callback = NativeBridge.callbacks[callbackId];
      if (!callback) return;
      callback.apply(null, resultArray);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
// Use this in javascript to request native objective-c code
// functionName : string (I think the name is explicit :p)
// args : array of arguments
// callback : function with n-arguments that is going to be called when the native code returned
  call: function (functionName, args, callback) {
    var hasCallback = callback && typeof callback == "function";
    var callbackId = hasCallback ? NativeBridge.callbacksCount++ : 0;
    if (hasCallback) {
      NativeBridge.callbacks[callbackId] = callback;
    }
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME”);
//esse nome é “native-brigdge-js” deve ser combinado conosco, ou mantém esse ou nos dê um para deixar igual
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "native-bridge-js:" + functionName + ":" + callbackId + ":" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(args)));
// For some reason we need to set a non-empty size for the iOS6 simulator...
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "1px");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "1px");
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
  }
};

if (test()) {
  NativeBridge.call('share', args, callback);
}
//verificar se é um aparelho android/ios
//Isso pode ser substituído por uma verificação de vocês!
//Essas Strings BaseWebviewAppIOS e BaseWebviewAppAndroid devem ser configuradas no Android ou no iOS
// para identificar que se trata dos nossos apps
// Isso se vocês forem usar esse método de verificação
var test = function () {
  return /[BaseWebviewAppIOS|BaseWebviewAppAndroid]$/.test(navigator.userAgent);
};
var testIOS = function () {
  return /BaseWebviewAppIOS$/.test(navigator.userAgent);
};
var testAndroid = function () {
  return /BaseWebviewAppAndroid$/.test(navigator.userAgent) && Android != undefined;
};
//ex: de funcoes pra salvar nos shared preferences no ANDROID
// salva e pega strings chave-valor
var get = function (key) {
if (testAndroid() && key != undefined) {
  var data = Android.getData(key);
  if (data != undefined) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }
 }
};
var set = function (key, data) {
  if (testAndroid()) {
    if (key != undefined) {
      if (data != undefined) {
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
     }
     Android.setData(key, data);
   }
  }
};
var getObject = function (key) {
  if (testAndroid()) {
//verifica se é um dispositivo android? se sim, usa os sharedpreferences
    return get(key);
  } else {
//se não, usa os cookies nativos do browser/iOS //(esse exemplo usa Angular)
    return $cookies.getObject(key);
  }
};
var putObject = function (key, data) {
  if (testAndroid()) {
//verifica se é um dispositivo android? se sim, usa os sharedpreferences
    set(key, data);
  } else {
//se não, usa os cookies nativos do browser/iOS
    $cookies.putObject(key, data);// (esse exemplo usa Angular)
  }
};
var remove = function (key) {
  if (testAndroid()) {
//verifica se é um dispositivo android? se sim, usa os sharedpreferences
   set(key, null);
  } else {
//se não, usa os cookies nativos do browser/iOS
   $cookies.remove(key); // (esse exemplo usa Angular)
  }
};
```

Exemplo de chamada:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function getFireBaseToken() {
NativeBridge.call("firebase", null, function (data) {
alert(data);
console.log(data);
//no caso vocês podem fazer algo mais interessante, enviar pra api de vocês, por exemplo
});
}

function saveSomeCookies() {
set('COOKIE', Math.random())
}

function getSomeCookies() {
cookies = get('COOKIE');
alert(cookies);
console.log(cookies);
}
</script>

<button onclick="getFireBaseToken()">Firebase Button</button>
<button onclick="saveSomeCookies()">Salvar Cookie</button>
<button onclick="getSomeCookies()">Pegar Cookies</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Para saber melhor como funciona essa interface na documentação da webview fala sobre ela:
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html